# Firebase Storage Rules, how to write in specific folder?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have theses rules for now :

EDIT

```
    rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

But I only want to let people write in specific folder so I don't want to override all the pictures in case something goes wrong.

By exemple, I wanna do something like this

```
  "Belgium" : {
    "ChatPicture" : {
      "write" = "true",
      "read"= "true"
    }
  }
```

I don't really understand why it is so different from the realtime database rules.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Realtime Database uses a completely different syntax than Realtime Database, so you'll have to learn something new.  It is the same language as used with Firestore rules.  I suggest starting with the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start

Comment: Also, on Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it as code so it's easy to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy to specify a path in [Storage security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start).

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /Belgium/ChatPicture/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is multiple country and multiple folder can it be :  match /$country/$folder/{allPaths=**} ? country being a variable

Comment: Sure, the documentation shows that you can use path wildcards with `{wildcard}`.  I suggest reading it over.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#wildcard_matches

Comment: I updated my answer [EDIT 2], could you please check ?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post it separately.  That's the convention on Stack Overflow.

Comment: should I open a new question and put the link here?

Comment: Sure, if you want.

Comment: Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61534818/firebase-storage-rules-acces-granted-dont-match-rules