# Firebase Storage Rules - access granted doesn't match rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Here is my rules :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{country}/{type}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason I can write and read in this path : `child(Test).child("Image.jpg")` but it shouldn't be. I should only be able to write and read in this path `child(Test).child(Test2).child("Image.jpg")`

Test and Test2 are both variables.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as I would expect.  In security rules version 2, recursive wildcards (`allPaths=**`) match 0 or more path segments.  So, your rule is matching `country=Test` and `type=Image.jpg` with nothing matched for `allPaths`.

If you want only two path segments, you'll have to get rid of the allPaths wildcard entirely.  Or, consider calling out specific top-level path components instead of wildcarding everything.

Comment: I think I got it, I edited the question with my news rules can you check if it is ok ?

Comment: Again, you've changed the question, which effecitvely invalidated my answer.  It seems now that you'll have to play around with it to best understand how it works, and determine what your requirements are for security rules.  I suspect that wildcarding everything is not really what you want.  I think you do understand how it works, though - you don't really need my validation.

Comment: If you have a very short followup, you can just reply to the answer as you did here.

Comment: Sorry, but thanks to you I understand now. 
Thank you for your help and thank you for the tips about stack overflow